# Extending isomorphisms of schemes of finite presentation over ring of integers

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F$ be a number field and let $S$ be a finite set of primes of $F$. Why does every isomorphism of two $\mathcal{O}_{F,S}$-schemes of finite presentation extend uniquely to an isomorphism over an open subset of Spec $\mathcal{O}_{F,S}$?

Comment: Did you mean open subset of $Spec\ O_F$, that is they would extend to $O_F[a^{-1}]$ schemes and so does the isomorphism ?

Comment: @reuns exactly.

Comment: ?? $O_{F,S} = \{ a/b, a,b \in O_F, \forall P \in S, b\not \in P\},Spec(O_{F,S}) = S$.